# How to capture(create javascript interface) Web View Response header while click on Login Button in IOS application obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

How to capture HTTP response headers in UIWebview,  when user finishes the registration from the web view, the app should be notified with the successful unique id assigned to the user on registration which is passed back in HTTP Response Headers.

Is there any direct way to capture/log the HTTP Response headers using

Thanks
Sushil

Answer (score 0):

If you should use UIWebview, you have two options to do that:

1. If the URL is cacheable, the simpliest solution would be:

   ```
   - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
       NSCachedURLResponse *resp = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:webView.request];
       NSLog(@"%@",[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)resp.response allHeaderFields]); // Show all HTTP header fields
   }
   ```
2. If not and as a general solution is to use a custom NSURLProtocol to handle all request/response

Comment: i am getting nil object from NSCachedURLResponse

Comment: can you explain me little bit to about NSURLProtocol,  means how to use , or can you provide me demo

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I am on holiday and I have not my Mac but you could find a good way to start at [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial) . The main message you should look at is _- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response_